# How do I get a company name from an IP address?

Tags: geolocation, ip, ip-address, whois

I've searched around a while and all of the IP --> Hostname things actually only end up giving an ISP. Is there something that goes beyond that? I'm only finding pay services that go further and not something that I can just tap a nice API and programmatically do it.

http://ipinfo.io/ just ends up showing ISP for many of what I've sampled. I saw that guy posts here fairly often.

whoisvisiting.com runs about $99/mnth for what my company site does but in that range I'd rather code something. I'm using the free trial right now and have the IP's logging to analytics so I'm looking at what it returns, what IIS returns as the hostname and what a couple sources like ipinfo.io show and whoisvisiting somehow actually shows what I'm looking for.

Comment: The http://ipinfo.io API offers the full company details (as opposed to the ASN, which is in the standard API response) as an optional add on. See https://ipinfo.io/data for details.

Comment: Which tool did you end up using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do so. There's no central registry for which company has which address ranges. In fact, most companies will just be identifiable via their ISP.

Your paid services might be scams, by the way, or just work on very few select companies and universities that actually act as autonomous entities in the IP sense.

Comment: This the only way to do is is some form of manual DB which will prove to not only be a lot of work but end up less accurate than you'd expect.

Comment: There are paid alternatives of course, my old company used one which was very reliable but unfortunately doesn't have realtime APIs. There are definitely ways to do it, but as you say it might manually mantained in some way.

Comment: @MacK I doubt that. If you can tell me how your paid alternative knows which IP addresses belong to Marcus Müller Engineering, or which IP address of that 100 offices block belong to the 5 companies using different floors of that building, I'd be interested. As said, it's easy if your company of interest is really large, but for the most part, you could just tell which uplink provider and which regional datacenter, nothing more.

Comment: I am not entirely sure how they get the data from, that's why I say it's probably manual entry as well as a bit of cross-referencing. In UK/London most small businesses have a static (or a range) of IP addresses allocated for them, maybe they end up in a registry or they simply collect data from other sources. I don't want to sponsor them, but if you search on google for Lead Forensics and your company is being detected you should see the company name on the first slide of the carousel (also, if you CTRL+F `manhattan` on the source there's their internal endpoint which replies with said data)

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely to differentiate between ISP or company IP address. Some geolocation providers will use range size or level of allocation to name ISP or business. However, this approach is not always accurate.